# Spring MVC view technology: what to choose?

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I want to create web-site with Spring back-end, but I can't choose what view technology to use: JSP, Velocity, or I should try to integrate JSF with my app. Which of this technologies is the most popular? 
Looks like that JSP is a quite deprecated technology, but I hasn't found a proof of this thesis yet. Should I learn JSP, or try some another framework?

Answer (score 2):

I´d use JSP+JSTL+Tiles, but mainly because everybody knows them. I could consider to use Freemarker or Velocity (Specially the first). However, I think Spring MVC and JSF are technologies that overlap, and using them together could be useless and dangerous.

I recommend you to take a look at this:  http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html

And also at this: http://ihatejsf.com/